# Div to repeat with distinct attributes from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-access

i have this this code which i want to be repeated depending on the amount of rows in my database(ms-access)
so what this is doing is it is displaying a image and a download button to download the music but at the moment it is just displaying one information how can i make the `DOWNLOAD_INFO` div to repeat depending on the amount of rows my database has
i hope i am being clear.

```
 <div id="DOWNLOAD_INFO">

           <!-- IMAGE display -->
        <img runat="server" id="image" src="images/test.png" 
         onclick="return musicimage_onclick()"><!-- END IMAGE display -->

            <!-- HEADING -->
       <h4><asp:Label ID="heading" runat="server" Text="heading of music"></h4>
            <!-- HEADING END-->

         <!-- DOWNLOAD BUTTON -->
       <asp:Button ID="download" runat="server" Text="Download"  
         onclick="downloadmusic_Click" />
             <!-- DOWNLOAD BUTTON END -->
    </div>
```

and in my C# side i have this

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM downloads", conn);
.
.
    while (reader.Read()) 
                        {
                            id = reader[0].ToString();
                            title= reader[1].ToString();
                            description= reader[2].ToString();
                            image= reader[3].ToString();
                            downloadsource = reader[3].ToString();
                            //adding it to the page
                            image.Attributes["src"] = "~/image/" + title+ "";
                            heading.Text = musicTitle;
                      }
```

**ms access database**

```
|id|title|imgsource  |downloadsource|

| 1| yay |  /yay.png | yay.mp3      |
| 2| test|  /test.png| test.mp3     |
```

**sample output**
[image]

Comment: do you use asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc?

Comment: i use  asp.net webforms